# how to add a configuration in ckeditor 5 in addition to the default configuration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ckeditor5

i have a default configuration in a file for create many editors ckeditor 5.

I have no problem in using but, i want create a root configuration and in others files import this editor and make many addition in configuration on the default configuration.

```
    Editor.defaultConfig = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'simplebox',
            'heading',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'link',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            '|',
            'outdent',
            'indent',
            '|',
            'imageUpload',
            'blockQuote',
            'insertTable',
            'mediaEmbed',
            'undo',
            'redo',
            'alignment',
            'code',
            'codeBlock',
            'findAndReplace',
            'highlight',
            'horizontalLine',
            'htmlEmbed',
            'imageInsert',
            'pageBreak',
            'removeFormat',
            'sourceEditing',
            'specialCharacters',
            'strikethrough',
            'subscript',
            'superscript',
            'textPartLanguage',
            'todoList',
            'underline',
            '|', 'placeholder'
        ]
    },
    placeholderConfig: {
        types: ['date', 'color', 'first name', 'surname']
    },
    language: 'fr',
    heading: {
        options: [
            { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraphe', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
            { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Titre 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
            { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Titre 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' },
            { model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title: 'Titre 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3' },
            { model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Titre 4', class: 'ck-heading_heading4' },
            { model: 'heading5', view: 'h5', title: 'Titre 5', class: 'ck-heading_heading5' },
            { model: 'heading6', view: 'h6', title: 'Titre 6', class: 'ck-heading_heading6' }
        ]
    },...
```

i import this editor and i want a additionnal configuration on the default configuration.

```
import BuildEditor from '/assets/ckeditor/build/ckeditor';
BuildEditor.create(e.element,
        {
            heading: {
                options: [
                    {
                        model: 'h3caret',
                        view: {
                            name: 'h3',
                            classes: 'ck-heading_caret'
                        },
                        title: '>h3',
                        class: 'ck-heading_caret',

                        // It needs to be converted before the standard 'heading2'.
                        converterPriority: 'high'
                    }
                ]
            },...
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to handle pagination. But if bing is loading additional images via ajax then that won't do it. .... Have you inspected the bing url?

Comment: yes, i have different result with search word identical. it's normally?

Comment: i have post a response.